# KML Layers suddently not appearing on embedded Google map

Tags: javascript, kml, google-maps-api

I have an embedded map on:

http://wtc.army.mil/modules/family%20and%20caregivers/sfacMap.html

I am receiving the error below in different forms related to the session id/token trailing after the GetViewportInfo? part of the request whenever I zoom in/out.

NetworkError: 500 Internal Server Error - [http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js/ViewportInfoService.GetViewportInfo?1m6&1m2&1d-52.02177634131835&2d-180&2m2&1d90&2d180&2u3&4sen-US&5e4&6sr%40275000000&7b0&8e90&9b0&10b1&callback=*xdc*._s8nn5v&token=34036](http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js/ViewportInfoService.GetViewportInfo?1m6&1m2&1d-52.02177634131835&2d-180&2m2&1d90&2d180&2u3&4sen-US&5e4&6sr%40275000000&7b0&8e90&9b0&10b1&callback=_xdc_._s8nn5v&token=34036)

This all of a sudden occurred when previously my marker overlay was working. The functionality was that the markers would display info from my kml when clicked. Currently this does not seem to be working and I have made no changes since it was functional.

Answer (score 1):

you have a couple of js bugs on your page...

```
window.onload=function()
{
     var formref=document.getElementById("switchform")
     indicateSelected(formref.choice)
}
```

there is no element with id = "switchform".  try fixing that.

and maybe try putting this:

```
<script language="JavaScript">
$(document).ready(function() {
 $(".topnav").accordion({
  accordion:true,
  speed: 400,
  closedSign: '+',
  openedSign: '-'
 });
});
</script>
```

at the bottom of your page...I am not familiar with accordion so this suggestion may not work...but it's throwing an error.
Once you fix existing bugs, it may help.

Comment: Thanks I'll give it a shot. I have been aware of those bugs, but I never really bothered to fix it because of other priorities as well as it never interfered with the functionality of the Google Maps Frame. Although I find it odd to have that error interfere with the Google Maps JS API if that is the case.

Comment: I tried removing those bits of code in the development environment and there was no change, so I reverted it and the next day my overlay is back on the map. I am guessing this was some kind of issue between Google Drive where my overlay was hosted and Google's own overlay rendering servers.